# How to force Mathematica to show the plots in one row?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

Consider we have two different plot commands in Mathematica. In the output there are one plot and another one below. But I want the output to be organized in one row: on the left there is one plot, while on the right there is another plot. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at `GraphicsRow`.

Comment: @andre The close votes have nothing to do with your answer, but with the question. Typing `plot row` in the help-center and the second hit is `GraphicsRow`.  We always have the standard that at least a minimum amount of work should be done by the OP which did not happen here. Therefore, this question will most likey be closed as "can be found in the documentation".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often use this kind of code :

```
gr00=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi}]
gr01=Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,2 Pi}]
Row[{gr00,gr01}]
```

[image]

- If you don't want to see the first two graphs, simply add `;` at the end of the lines of code
- The two graphs in the same row are shrinked. To avoid the shrinking, you can do `Style[Row[{gr00,gr01}],ImageSizeMultipliers->{1, 1}]`.
- If the two graphs take more space that the windows width, the second graph is displayed under the first one (resulting in a layout that looks like a column). Simply enlarge the windows width and you will see immediatly the two graphs one next to the other.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know whether is possible to get 3 plots in one row? I tried, but it still displays maximum two plots.

Comment: @JohnTaylor I don't understand what you mean. It works fine with `gr00=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi}];
gr01=Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,2 Pi}];
gr02=Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,2 Pi}];
Row[{gr00,gr01,gr02}]`

Comment: @JohnTaylor this works too : `Style[Row[{gr00,gr01,gr02}],ImageSizeMultipliers->{1, 1}]` ( `{1,1}` , not `{1,1,1}`)